# Web Service call using desired network adapter

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

Is there any way to force Apache CXF to use specific network adapter?

I have generated soap web service proxy class using Jax-WS and calling service by using code below. I just want to invoke service by using Wireless network adapter without disabling wired ethernet connection.

```
FooService oServ = new FooWSService();              
FooWS oWs = oServ.getFooWSPort();               
String endpointURL = "https://fooservice/serviceWSPort";              
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) oWs;

Map<String, Object> requestContext = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointURL);             

org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(oWs);
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

String result = oWS.TestMethod();
```

Avaible network adapters in system by using

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
```

Result:

```
Display name: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Name: eth4
InetAddress: /fe80:0:0:0:914b:ee4a:58b7:e5b3%12
InetAddress: /10.10.10.227

Display name: 1x1 11b/g/n Wireless LAN PCI Express Half Mini Card Adapter
Name: net4
InetAddress: /fe80:0:0:0:513:7a5a:d3ab:9278%13
InetAddress: /10.10.11.35
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure, wether it is possible to configure web service client to bind requests to the specific interface, but I think you can do it with Host OS ip routing configuration easily. For windows you can do it like:

```
route ADD 1.1.1.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.10.11.35
```

Where `1.1.1.1` is the IP-address if fooservice and 10.10.11.35 is the address of the network interface, wich will be used as the gateway. You can make this route permanent if you need it with `-p` flag. For Linux it could be done in similar way.